# How to create a button which takes a picture

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, camera

I'm writing a cross-platform (iOS and Android) app in C# using Xamarin on Visual Studio Community 2022. I have implemented a camera preview on the app using the code found at this website :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-custom-camera-view-basic-concept-create-half-screen-camera-in-xamari/

The code on the website is for iOS, but there is a link at the bottom to download a folder which contains the code for Android as well. My app now displays a camera preview, but there is no way to take a picture with this. I therefore want to create a button which takes a picture without having to open the camera app. I'd also like the resulting photo to not be saved in the photos of the phone. I have looked but have found no way of doing exactly what I want, and therefore I don't know where to get started. If the answer could give as many details as possible about how to do this for both platforms it would be appreciated. Also, would the resulting photo be of the type FileResult? I have previously worked with the mediapicker in Xamarin which returns the type FileResult, but have come to realize that there are limitations within the mediapicker and I therefore can't work with it.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: google `xamarin android camera api` and `xamarin ios camera api`. Learn from the various links you find. If you have problems, come back to StackOverflow and post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MediaPicker to capture picture.And get the filepath in `photo.FullPath`.
You can refer to the link below to get more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=ios

**edit:**

```
private void cameraView_MediaCaptured(object sender, Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
 {
     byte[] image = e.ImageData;
     DependencyService.Get<ISaveService>().wirteFile("pic.jpg", image);
 }

 public interface ISaveService
 {
     void SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] data);
 }
```

**Android:**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SaveService))]
 namespace cameraviewDemo.Droid
 {
     public class SaveService: ISaveService
     {
         void ISaveService.SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
         {
             string picPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
             string filePath = Path.Combine(picPath, fileName);
             File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
         }
     }
 }
```

**iOS:**

```
 [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SaveService))]
 namespace cameraviewDemo.iOS
 {
     class SaveService: ISaveService
     {
         void ISaveService.SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] data)
         {
             var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
             var filename = Path.Combine(documents, fileName);
             File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I can't use the mediapicker. I want to be able to display the device orientation while taking the photo. The mediapicker doesn't allow for this, from what I gather. I have a preview of the camera already in my app but I'm looking for a way to make a button along with the preview which takes a photo.

Comment: maybe you can try cameraview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview

Comment: Thanks! I just finished implementing the code and it works! By any chance, do you have any idea on how to get the path to a photo with this? I'm using the Shutter() method to take a picture. Thanks!

Comment: you can save file with dependency service like edit shows.